# R shiny error with renderTable

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a shiny app for doing some network analyses. I want to calculate properties for the network using a function that is stored in `global.R`. However, I am not able to get the table output.

Here is the the part of my `ui.R` where I set the output for the table

```
        # More ui.R above
         mainPanel(
                    tabsetPanel(id = "conditionedPanels",

                        tabPanel("Network Properties",br(),value = 1,
                                 actionButton('netproperty', label='Calculate Properties',class="btn btn-primary"),
                                  h3(textOutput("Data Summary", container = span)),
                                  tableOutput('prop_table')),

                     ##... More ui.R code below
```

and here is my `server.R`:

```
shinyServer( function(input, output, session) {

 ## Get the properties
 props <- reactive({

  if (input$netproperty <= 0){
     return(NULL)
  }
  result <- isolate({
     input$netproperty
     tryCatch ({

     if(input$data_input_type=="example"){

         if(input$datasets == "Network1"){
           load("data/Network1.rda")
             props <- graph_topology(g)
             props
         } else if (input$datasets == "Network2"){
             load("data/Network1.rda")
             props <- graph_topology(g)
             props
         } else if (input$datasets == "Network3"){
            el <- read.delim("data/Network3.txt")
             g <- graph.data.frame(el, directed = FALSE)
             props <- graph_topology(g)
             props
         } else if (input$datasets == "Network4") {
            el <- read.delim("data/Network4.txt")
             g <- graph.data.frame(el, directed = FALSE)
             props <- graph_topology(g)
             props
         }
    } else if (input$data_input_type=="custom"){
        if (is.null(input$dt_file))
            return(NULL)
             inFile <- input$dt_file
             dataDT <- as.matrix(read.delim(inFile$datapah, sep="\t", header = FALSE, fill = TRUE))
             g <- graph.data.frame(dataDT, directed = FALSE)
             props <- graph_topology(g)
             props
     }
   },
     error = function(err) {
         print(paste("Select Example or custom data set"))
     })
 })
 result

})



## Output properties table
 output$prop_table <- renderTable({
   props()

 })
 }
```

When I press the button `calculate properties`, I get the error message always, telling me that I need to select example or custom data. I have tried with custom and example datasets, and the error remains. If I remove the `tryCatch` command in `server.R` I get the error of length equal zero. It seems that the function `graph_topology` in my `global.R` files is not working properly, but if I run it outside of the shiny app I get a matrix, that I thought it could be easily visualize with `renderTable`. I have also tried instead of using `uiOutput` in the `ui.R` using `tableOutput` but I have the same problem.

Comment: Please reduce the problem as much as you can while preserving the error, then provide an entire MWE (fully reproducible), including data. (It's usually much easier if you can use a dataset included in R or one of the standard packages). Also, please include the actual error text, it's very useful. (BTW: perhaps `req(input$datasets)` at the beginning of the `reactive` block would help.)

Comment: It's probably not related to your problem, but `eventReactive()` is designed exactly for a situation like this where you want an event (like clicking a button) to activate a code block which returns a reactive expression. And, yes, **please** include the error message!

Comment: the error I got is the one defined in my the server.r: `Select Example or custom data set`, if I remove the `tryCatch` the error I got is `Error: argument is of length zero`

Comment: I interpret that error to mean that this block is firing before `input$datasets` is properly set. Try `if (NULL=="a") 1 else 2`. Did anything happen when you added `req(input$datasets)` to the beginning of that `reactive` block?

Comment: @r2evans, the problem was before, you were right I was using `input$data_input_type` in my server but in my ui the inputID was declared as `data_type_input`, thanks a lot for the help, your suggestions gave me the clue